# Given $f(x)=x^3+x^2-x+2=0$ calculate $3$ iterations at$x_0=-2.4$

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

> Given $f(x)=x^3+x^2-x+2=0$
>
> 1. Find an interval[a,b] such that there exists $1$ and only root
> 2. Find a function $\phi(x)=x$
> 3. Find an interval where it is possible to use the simple iteration method and calculate $3$ iterations at initial value $x_0=-2.4$

---

What I tried:

1. Using intermediate value theorem we have $f(-1)=3$ and $f(-3)=-13$ so there is at least $1$ root, I showed there this root is the only one using rolls theorem.. Assume by contradiction there are $2$ different roots $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ the function is continuous and differentiable so there is a root $x_1 <c <x_2$ such that $f'(c)=0$ but $f'(x)=3x^2+2x-1=(x+1)(3x-1)=0$ so the roots are $c_1=-1$ and $c_2=\frac{1}{3}$ and there is only one of them in $[-3,-1]$
2. I added $x$ to both sides and got $x=x^3+x^2+2$ and then $\phi(x)=x^3+x^2+2$ we know that it converges if $max|\phi'(x)|<1$ so I solved $3x^2+2x<1$ and got $x \in (-1,\frac{1}{3})$but I don't know how to pick the interval from here is it $(-1,\frac{1}{3})$ or something else
3. When I first use $x_0=-2.4$ on $\phi(x)$ the function seems to diverge rather than converge..

$\phi(-2.4)=(-2.4)^3+(-2.4)^2-(-2.4)+2=-3.664$

$\phi(-3.664)=(-3.664)^3+(-3.664)^2-(-3.664)+2=-30.09992$

$\phi(-30.09992)=(-30.09992)^3+(-30.09992)^2-(-30.09992)+2=-26392.78612$

I am obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure it out

thanks for any help and tips

Comment: $f(x)$ is not convex, thus building $\phi(x)=f(x)$ should not work. Moreover, $f(x) = (x+2) \times (x^2-x+1)$, maybe already knowing the solution of $f(x)$ will help with the problem

Comment: @LeoJi I am sorry I don't really understand why it would not work? I am trying to practice the fixed point iteration topic
I know that the root for $f(x)$ is $-2$ but this is a problem I saw on the book and I am trying to solve the way they request
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $\phi(x)=-(x^2-x+2)^{1/3}$ works.

We have
$$\phi'(x)=\frac{-2x+1}{3(x^2-x+2)^{2/3}}$$
and
$$\phi''(x)=\frac{2(x^2-x-5)}{9(x^2-x+2)^{5/3}}$$
So, we can say that for $-3\lt x\lt \frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2}\approx -1.79$, $\phi''(x)\gt 0$ holds.

Since
$$|\phi'(-3)|=\frac{14^{1/3}}{6}\lt 1$$
$$\bigg|\phi'\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2}\bigg)\bigg|=\frac{7^{1/3}}{\sqrt{21}}\lt 1$$
we can say that, for $-3\lt x\lt \frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2}\approx -1.79$, $|\phi'(x)|\lt 1$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that, for convergence, we must have

$$|\phi'(x)|\le k \lt 1~~~\mbox{for all}~ x\in(a,b)$$

Does your choice of $\phi(x)$ satisfy that for the interval $(a, b) = (-3, -1)$ you found?

There are many ways to select candidate $\phi(x)$ functions and not all of them will work.

For example, we could have chosen

- $x = \phi_1(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 2$
- $x = \phi_2(x) = \pm \sqrt{x^3-x+2}$
- $x = \phi_3(x) = -\dfrac{2}{x^2+x-1}$
- $x = \phi_4(x) = (-x^2 + x -2)^{1/3}$
- $x = \phi_5(x) = x - \dfrac{x^3+x^2-x+2}{3x^2+2x-1}$

Try these and see what you get as iterates.

Do you recognize the last one? Which of these converge?

Comment: thanks for the help, I see that $\phi_5(x)$ is similar to  Newton–Raphson method
after doing the derivative I get $\frac{6x^4+8x^3-4x^2+10x+4}{(3x^2+2x-1)^2}$ but I am still confused on how to find the interval from here I know that most of the time newton method does converge but how to actually prove it here

Comment: Try plotting it or just try reducing the range, something like $(-2.5,-1.8)$. That is the tricky part and is more an art than a science. You can also try plotting it and eyeballing it and seeing if you can figure out the range. You can also try trial and error. You can mostly be assured that it works as you already proved there is a root there.

Comment: A Computer Algebra System is able to solve $|\frac{6x^4+8x^3-4x^2+10x+4}{(3x^2+2x-1)^2}| < 1$, see: [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7C%28%282+%2B+6+x%29+%282+-+x+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+x%5E3%29%29%2F%28-1+%2B+2+x+%2B+3+x%5E2%29%5E2+%7C%3C+1) because the plot is quite nasty. Also note, you found the interval to initially try by bounding a range for the root. It did not work here and we have to reduce it to get it into a good bound. Normally, the bounding is enough.